# Merge JSON arrays on dissimilar keys

Tags: jq, merge

I have 2 JSON files with arrays (extracted from restAPI using curl in bash). Both files are arrays with a `.result` object at the top which needs to remain.    The first has a `.name` field and many (over 100) other fields including `.ip_address` which is blank.   The second has additional information like interface and ip address and the name (key) in a different field name.  The key in the first file is not the same as the key in the second but should be related (I could change the key field name of course before and the key's data is often mixed case)

I want to merge them so that the first JSON's `ip_address` is overwritten where the `.name` fields are the same and the additional data added:

I get that it's either multiplying the arrays or reducing and adding but I can't get it right based on the examples already found.  For a solution, I would be most grateful.

**Servers:**

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "os": "Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard",
      "name": "SERVER1",
      "ip_address": ""
    },
    {
      "os": "Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard",
      "name": "SERVER2",
      "ip_address": ""
    },
    {
      "os": "Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard",
      "name": "server3",
      "ip_address": ""
     },
    {
      "os": "Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard",
      "name": "server4",
      "ip_address": ""
     }
  ]
}
```

**ips.txt**

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "interface": "Intel Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz",
      "cmdb.name": "server1",
      "ip_address": "10.0.0.10"
    },
    {
      "interface": "Wi-Fi",
      "cmdb.name": "server2",
      "ip_address": "10.0.0.10"
    },
    {
      "interface": "Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265",
      "cmdb.name": "server4",
      "ip_address": "10.0.0.10"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Desired output of Server data is:**

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "os": "Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard",
      "name": "SERVER1",
      "interface": "Intel Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz",
      "ip_address": "10.0.0.10"
    },
    {
      "os": "Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard",
      "name": "SERVER2",
      "interface": "Wi-Fi",
      "ip_address": "10.0.0.10"
    },
    {
      "os": "Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard",
      "name": "server3",
      "ip_address": ""
     },
    {
      "os": "Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard",
      "name": "server4",
      "interface": "Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265",
      "ip_address": "10.0.0.10"
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What happens if the **Server** array defines an `"ip_address"` field which is not `""`?

Comment: Just overwrite it.

Comment: Have you tried to look at writing a Node.js script to do that work? I would imagine the arrays may not be sorted? (i.e. the names in one array may not be sorted like the names in another array?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following uses the relational `JOIN()` function in `jq` to join the two `result` arrays on the elements that are equal with respect to the lower-case variant of the `name` key (servers) and the `cmdb.name` key (IPs).  It also uses `INDEX()` to build an index of the IP file's `result` array.  The `JOIN()` function gives us arrays (pairs in the example) of matching objects that we merge using the `add` function. After joining and merging, we are left with objects containing both the `name` and the `cmdb.name` keys, so we delete the latter in each object.

```bash
jq '.result = [JOIN(INDEX(input.result[]; ."cmdb.name"|ascii_downcase); .result[]; .name|ascii_downcase) | add | del(."cmdb.name")]' servers.json ips.json
```

The `jq` expression, nicely formatted:

```
.result =
  [
    JOIN(
      # index on the second file's .cmdb.name key in each result object
      INDEX(
        input.result[];
        ."cmdb.name" | ascii_downcase
      );
      .result[];             # join on the first file's result objects
      .name | ascii_downcase # match using the .name key
    )
    | add               # merge the matched objects
    | del(."cmdb.name") # delete that key we don't want
  ]
```

Result:

```json
{
  "result": [
    {
      "os": "Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard",
      "name": "SERVER1",
      "ip_address": "10.0.0.10",
      "interface": "Intel Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz"
    },
    {
      "os": "Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard",
      "name": "SERVER2",
      "ip_address": "10.0.0.10",
      "interface": "Wi-Fi"
    },
    {
      "os": "Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard",
      "name": "server3",
      "ip_address": ""
    },
    {
      "os": "Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard",
      "name": "server4",
      "ip_address": "10.0.0.10",
      "interface": "Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you kindly. Will test it with the real data set. The power of JQ just amazes me.

Comment: works perfectly.